# jquery function on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this short piece of code, it should be executed when loading the page and not on the attached event. I can't figure out how to do that. Can someone help me out ?

```
$("#set_strokes_show input").on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    live.tiles.strikes_toggle($("input[name='set_strokes_shw']:checked").val() == '1');
});
```

Comment: Remove the line of code from the event handler, and put it directly inside the document ready block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it *just* at page load, then simply remove it from the event handler:*

```
live.tiles.strikes_toggle($("input[name='set_strokes_shw']:checked").val() == '1');
```

If you need it on page load *and* in response to the event, make it a function you can call in both places:

```
function tilesHandler() {
    live.tiles.strikes_toggle($("input[name='set_strokes_shw']:checked").val() == '1');
}
tilesHandler();
$("#set_strokes_show input").on('click touchstart', tilesHandler);
```

---

* This assumes the code is in a `script` tag *after* the relevant elements in the HTML, or that it's inside a [`ready` handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready). If not, move the script to the bottom of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag (preferred), or put it in a `ready` handler.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#set_strokes_show input").click();
```